# How to Blink a line on a map similarly like a point blinking on map through lat lon points

Tags: openlayers-2, linestring, line

how to blink a line on a map which is formed by lat lon points through linestring from database the points(lat,lon) comes which is stored in form of MultiLineString.
similarly like how a point blinking on a map same way the line should blink on map.
(or)

I need to show on a map line blinking below code is displaying a line on the map but it should be made line blinking not all but particular some lines.

code :-

```
var mainfed = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Mainfed");

$.get('http://'localhost:90'/them/date-feeder.php',function(data) { //getting the data from DB through php

   var records = data.split(',<br>'); //recognize the lat,lon through splitting the  records

 for(var idx=0;idx<records.length;idx++)
  {
    var myarr = records[idx].split(",");
    var points = new Array()
    for(i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++)
    {
        var lon = parseFloat(myarr[i++]);
        var lat = parseFloat(myarr[i]);

                      points.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon,lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()) );
    }
         var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
         var style = {
         'class': 'lineblink',
          strokeColor: 'red', 
          strokeOpacity: 5,
          strokeWidth: 2
          };
 var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style); 
    mainfed.addFeatures([lineFeature]); // forming a line through points            
         }
});
    map.addLayer(mainfed); 
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(mainfed, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using rules to select the needed lines, 
and then use symbolizer: {display:'none'  } to hide matching lines, and "normal" symbolizer to show it on again.

and then using javascript timing (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) that switches Rule objects that turn lines on and off.